# get MAX from SUM in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

```
    player = LOAD 'ass2_player' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
player = FOREACH player GENERATE
    (chararray)$3 AS tmID,
    (int)$1 AS year,
    (int)$8 AS points;
group_data = GROUP player BY (year, tmID);
sum_data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE group, SUM(player.points) AS tot_points;
max_data = FOREACH sum_data GENERATE FLATTEN(group), MAX(sum_data.tot_points);
DUMP max_data;
```

I just want to select the tmID of team which has the highest point for EACH  YEAR.

How to get the whole row or partial fields or the row with the max value.
like, after group by year, the group only contains "year" and tuple will take the "tmID, tot_points". How do I got like:
(year, tmID, tot_points) for each YEAR.

Comment: can you add sample input and expected output for your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  Here is the schema for `sum_data`:

```
((year, tmID), tot_points)
```

From here, you need to `group` on year and take `max` on `tot_points`. It will be easier if you `flatten` group in the `sum_data` step only, such as:

```
sum_data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE flatten(group) as (year, tmID), SUM(player.points) AS tot_points;

sum_data_grouped = GROUP sum_data BY year;
max_data = FOREACH sum_data_grouped GENERATE group AS year, MAX(sum_data.tot_points) AS max_points, sum_data.tmpID AS tmID;
```

Your final script should look something like this:

```
player = LOAD 'ass2_player' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
player = FOREACH player GENERATE (chararray)$3 AS tmID, (int)$1 AS year, (int)$8 AS points;
group_data = GROUP player BY (year, tmID);
sum_data = FOREACH group_data GENERATE flatten(group) AS (year, tmID), SUM(player.points) AS tot_points;
sum_data_grouped = GROUP sum_data BY year;
max_data = FOREACH sum_data_grouped GENERATE group AS year, MAX(sum_data.tot_points) AS max_points, sum_data.tmpID AS tmID;
```

PS:  I wrote this on my mobile and didn't test this. Let me know what you get.